# вывод товаров на страницу с помощью базы данных через блок категорий

Tags: php, mysql

Код сравнивает с тем что есть в запросе и то что есть в базе. 
Однако при выведению на страницу выбор по брэнду не происходит, то есть при нажатии на apple не показывает только телефон apple, а вообще выводиться вся база, которая пока состоит из трёх товаров, Apple, Samsung и Nokia. Запрос в базе тоже вроде пишется правильно

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$link);

    if (!empty($cat) && !empty($type))
     {

         $querycat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_tovara='$type'";

     }else
     {

        if (!empty($type))
        {
            $querycat = "AND type_tovara='$type'";
        }else
        {
            $querycat = "";
        }

     }
```

Необходимо, чтобы выбор происходил правильно, выбираю apple выводит один телефон apple, также с samsung и nokia. Проверил несколько раз, но ошибку не вижу, нашел ошибку в переменной, но не исчезла проблема, всё равно не выводит то, что нужно. Вот в запросе нет =, (между cat и apple) скорее всего оно там должно быть, так как при введение туда =, происходит то, что нужно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там строчка $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$link); идёт ниже основного кода уже в запросах.

Comment: Нет не могу найти, однако сподвижки всё-таки есть, вроде бы отличия на страницах view_cat.php и index.php должны быть.

Answer (score 0):

`echo'<li><a href="view_cat.php?cat='.strtolower($row["brand"]).'&type='.$row["type"].'">'.$row["brand"].'</a></li>` после cat добавил = на странице блока категорий